# Petsc's xxxSetxxx methods: Own Pointer or Copy Values?

Tags: petsc

In PETSC, there are many xxxSetyyy methods, e.g. MatSetLocalToGlobalMapping(A,rmap,cmap).  I wonder whether contents of rmap and cmap (or generally yyy, that set to xxx) pointing to are copied to somewhere in A (or xxx).  In other words, shall I destroy 'yyy' after set to 'xxx' or I should not before finish using 'yyy' inside 'xxx'?

Other examples include KSPSetPC, PCCompositeAddPC(PC pc,PCType type), ISCreateGeneral, PCASMSetLocalSubdomains. I found that for PCASMSetLocalSubdomains the IS defining the subdomains are **copied** so we can destroy it afterwards. On the other hand, ISCreateGeneral forward a parameter to let user specify PetscCopyMode (Own_Pointer or Copy_Values).

Is there any general rule for these things?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When there is a ***PetscCopyMode*** parameter, the behavior is explicit. We would like to be explicit in every instance, but that would become very cumbersome in the interface.

***Create***() gives back a new reference, whereas ***Get***() returns a borrowed reference and should be given back using ***Restore***().

The exceptions come up in ***Set***() methods. They should all reference objects, and most do such as KSPSetPC(), however since this change was made relatively recently (and sometimes does not make as much sense), there are a few exceptions left. They will all eventually be documented/fixed. Please report any inconsistencies.The ***Get***() methods generally return a borrowed reference since it is so cumbersome to destroy the object each time.

Answer (score 4):

In general, the `Set` methods (and PETSc) pass-by-reference, so it is not safe to destroy the object that you have passed to the method.  Methods such as `PCASMSetLocalSubdomains` are the exceptions, not the rules.